# Where and how can I add a wait for page to load in my script?

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to JS im having an issue at the moment where my axe chrome extension isn't matching up with the below script. A suggestion would be to wait for the page to load however Im a bit confused about what to use and where to use it? Hoping that waiting for the page load will allow me to view the AA issues that aren't being pulled through.

```
const driver = new WebDriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
    
    driver.get('MySite').then( () => {
        new AxeBuilder(driver).withTags(['wcag2a', 'wcag2aa', 'wcag21a', 'wcag21aa', 'best-practice', 'wcag***', 'act', 'section508', 'section508.*.*', 'experimental', 'cat.*', 'color-contrast'])
            .analyze((err, results) => {
            if (err) {
                // Handle error somehow
            }
            console.log(results.violations);
        });
    
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

To wait for the page to load, wrap your script in the following:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // ...your code here...
}
```

See [onload documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload).

Alternatively, move the `<script>` tag to the bottom of the HTML (and don't use the `async` attribute).

Answer (score 0):

For classic scripts, if the async attribute is present, then the classic script will be fetched in parallel to parsing and evaluated as soon as it is available.
read this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-async

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm still none the wiser after reading it.